# Temporary Variable Not Being Stored In Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, selection-sort

I am building a sorting algorithm (Selection Sort) and have been able to complete it. However, if I want to add a temporary variable, which stores the unsorted array, it seems to be immediately changed to the sorted array:

```
 var A = [-8, 1, 77, -99, 3, 5];
 function findMin(A,startIndex,endIndex) {
 var temp = startIndex;
 for(var x = startIndex; x <= endIndex; x++){


 if(A[temp] > A[x]) {

   temp = x;

}

}
return temp;
}
function swapNumbers(A, index1, index2) {
var temp_2 = A[index1];
A[index1] = A[index2];
A[index2] = temp_2;

return A;
}

function sort(A) {
var endofArray = A.length - 1;
var temp3 = A;
var Asorted = [];
for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    swapNumbers(A, i, findMin(A, i, endofArray));

}
Asorted = A;
console.log("The unsorted array was " + "[" + temp3 + "]" 
+ "." + " The sorted array is " + "[" + Asorted + "]" + "."); 
return Asorted; /*subsitute return for 
console.log() to display results*/
}
sort(A);
```

The `temp3` in `console.log("The unsorted array was " + "[" + temp3 + "]" 
 + "." + " The sorted array is " + "[" + Asorted + "]" + ".");` seems to output:

`The unsorted array was [-99,-8,1,3,5,77]. The sorted array is [-99,-8,1,3,5,77].`

instead of:

`The unsorted array was [-8, 1, 77, -99, 3, 5]. The sorted array is [-99,-8,1,3,5,77].`

Please inform me of my mistake.
   `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

When you assign temp3 to A, you're basically just pointing to the A array in memory, not actually copying the array. Try:

```
var temp3 = A.slice();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice